# LaunchFileAsync deactivates the application in Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am opening an image using Launcher, the image is being opened in the photo viewer, but the application gets crashed with ApplicationNotHandledException.

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
```

I also added fast app resume option in manifest file and I am using emulator of 512 MB RAM

Is there anything need to be done further?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that 'file' is not null?
On MSDN good [sample how to use LaunchFileAsyb](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Association-Launching-535d2cec/sourcecode?fileId=43565&pathId=922494205)

Comment: yes file is not null, I mentioned in the question that, the file is opening